# при поиске исчезает запятая в массиве

Tags: javascript, css

В общем при поиске, исчезает запятая если 2 должности. Если искать вручную имя, то запятая присутствует.

```js
positionsName() { // на случай если должности будут в массиве
  let positionList = this.props.positionsList;
  if (positionList && Array.isArray(positionList) && positionList.length !== 0) {
    return positionList.map((each, index) => {
      return ( <
        span key = {
          index
        } > {
          each.label
        } {
          positionList.length > 1 && positionList.length < -1 !== index ? ',' : ''
        } < /span>
      );
    });
  } else {
    return ( <
      span key = "position_name" > {
        this.props.positionsName
      } < /span>
    );
  }
}
```

Данная функция используется здесь

```
<div className="contact-description">
    <div>
      <div
          className={
               !usersForChat ? read ? "textSearchUnitRead contact- 
               description-item" 
               : "textSearchUnit contact-description-item" 
               : "contact-description-item"
          }
          style={{
              color: color,
              maxHeight: 28,
              maxWidth: 300,
              margin: '1px 0px',
              whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
          }}
        >{number}</div>
        <div
          style={{
            color: 'grey',
            maxHeight: 28,
            width: 200,
            lineHeight: '14px',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
          }}
        >{label}</div>
{this.props.visiblePosition && this.props.positionsName ? 
  <div className = 
    "user-position-right-panel"
  >{this.positionsName()}
  </div> 
    : ""
  }
  </div>
```

Comment: отформатируй свою разметку

Comment: @Grundy как то так

Comment: `positionList.length < -1 !== index` - очень странное сравнение. Что ты тут пытался сделать?

Comment: @Grundy я сам в шоке от такого, но код не мой и я стажируюсь 2 недели, как то так. Мне оно не понравилось тож

Comment: в общем это условие неверное, тебе его надо изменить: определись что именно тут нужно проверить и поменяй условие на нужное

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в некорректном условии.

```
positionList.length > 1 && positionList.length < -1 !== index ? ',' : ''
```

В данном случае тут идет определение нужно ли ставить запятую либо нет.

Правило простое: если больше одного элемента, и элемент не последний - поставить после него запятую.

За первую часть отвечает проверка `positionList.length > 1`

А вот со второй - проблема. Для проверки, что элемент не последний, нужно сравнить его индекс, с максимальным индексом в массиве (length-1), то есть условие должно выглядеть так:

```
index < positionList.length - 1
```

Comment: к сожалаению, не работает :(

Comment: @Oleksey, работает :)

Comment: у меня в коде запятая не исчезала, а когда в поисковой строке вводил - исчезала) Щас пока другую делаю задачу, потом еще раз пересмотрю эту.